# JPA transform left join in inner join

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this request with JPA :

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM BonSav b " +
    "LEFT JOIN b.destinataire r " +
    "LEFT JOIN b.entite e " +
    "LEFT JOIN b.type t " +
    "LEFT JOIN b.etat et" +
    "LEFT JOIN b.lieu l " +
    "LEFT JOIN b.nature n " +
    "WHERE b.id = :id " +
    "AND b.estSupprimer = false" )
BonSav findOneWithAllEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
```

When I launch this request, the left join for field "lieu" was transformed in "inner join", I don't understand why;

have you an idea for resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: i think your query need a space in the end of `"LEFT JOIN b.etat et"`

Comment: nice!!! it was easy.. I don't understant why I not found it. Thanks

Comment: @YCF_L just post that as an answer ^^

Comment: I usually put spaces at the **beginning** of each line, rather than the end. This makes it easier to spot such mistakes, because the first non-whitespace characters are not aligned anymore. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: @Lino i think it is a typo no? ^^

Comment: @YCF_L it is, but yours is still an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a typo.
try putting a space after "et" in line  `"LEFT JOIN b.etat et" +`

As there was no space JPA was making query as **etLEFT JOIN** and by default **JOIN** is treated as **INNER JOIN**.